# Functions / App Services memory in shared environments secure from probing documentation - Cross Tenant Hacking

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

Query from client re Cross Tenant Hacking.  Can’t seem to find the exact verbiage to address their concerns re consumption plan.  Probably be something re functions and app service managed runtimes and not being able to “poke” out into other areas memory.  Anyone got anything?

I’m also going to talk to them about ASE for functions, premium plans, and such.

“We've been asked how you protect access to memory in Azure PaaS, specifically Functions. I assume that if I run a function, the memory for that function is not available for someone else's function (so they can't snoop).  Can you supply documentation on this?”

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

All Azure Web Apps (as well as Mobile App/Services, WebJobs and Functions) run in a secure environment called [Azure Web App Sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). This is the case of Windows Plans.

In case of Linux Plans, apps run inside of a (docker) container as mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2693#issuecomment-364793670) which inherently provides isolation.

Comment: Thanks Pramod, that is exactly the links I couldn't find!